# window.location.assign not working

Tags: javascript, php, redirect

I have the following code:

```
function verifyUser(userEmail){
$.getJSON('verifyUser.php', {data : userEmail}, function(result){
    console.log(result);
alert(result.location);
console.log(window.location.href);
    window.location.href = "http://localhost/hub.php";
console.log(window.location.href);
console.log(result);
alert(result.location);
});
```

};

Where I get a JSON returned with the name of the user, the email, the location:

```
while($row = $resultQuery->fetch_assoc()){
            $_SESSION['userName'] = $row['USERID'];
            $_SESSION['userRole'] = $row['USERROLE'];
            $returnDataLogin['success'] = true;
            $returnDataLogin['email'] = $email;
            $returnDataLogin['role'] = $row['USERROLE'];
            $returnDataLogin['location'] = 'http://localhost/hub.php';
            $returnDataLogin['message'] = 'Bienvenido '.$returnDataLogin['email'].'!';
            $json_data = json_encode($returnDataLogin, JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES);
            echo $json_data;
}
```

then I assign on the javascript function the location of the window. It works flawlessly on WAMP server, however, it does not redirect once I move the files to apache server. Any ideas what might be wrong?

**EDIT:**

I found that the request does not follow, it throws a 302 (Found):

[image]

Comment: Are your PHP and JS files on separate domains?

Comment: Apache is part of WAMP, you're going between two Apache servers, it's likely not the issue.

Comment: No! They are on the same domain, on the same server.

Comment: So what does the request get redirected to with the `302` response?